# Does Meteor up (MUP) works exactly as Docker Automated Builds?

Tags: meteor, docker

The question is more precisely, does those commands work in the same way ? :

```
mup setup 
mup deploy
```

AND :

```
docker run X
```

Where X would be an image with mongoDB/node/phantomJS ect..

I am currently trying to understand the exact point of Docker, and from what I've seen, automated builds works pretty much in the same way, i.e : Setting the environnement by running pre-written commands.

The difference being in Docker running those commands to set the environnement inside a container, whereas MUP install everything directly on the server/VM.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: mup correctly doesn't use docker, but mupx, the next version of mup, does.